Embedding of sequence of events sets
My data can be represented as a sequence of events; each event is a set of elements. Events appear one-by-one in time; elements appear all together within the event.
Example: event_t1: {A, B, C}, event_t2: {B, C, F}, event_t3: {A, C, D}.
t1, t2, t3 are time indicators, t1 < t2 < t3.
Within each event elements cannot be ordered.
I'm interesting in elements' embedding. If each event would contain only 1 element, I would be able to represent each sequence of elements as a "sentence" and use one of available embedding methods (word2vec etc.). However, here two types of dependencies exist: in time and indirect links within an event.
Do you have any idea how to embed elements (with Python)?
